# List children pages of multiple parent pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to list children pages of the several parent pages.

I have child_of property but it is listing only one ID, so I can list Id-403 but not  403,414,417. Have you guys any idea how I can do it?

I tried this but it is not working with multiple pages.

```
  <div id="archive-thumbnails-listing" >
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 379, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' )); ?>
<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
<div class="thumb12wrap">
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a>
<div class="shade23desc" ><a class="desc"  href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
</div>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

WIll be happy for any help!

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what you have done and what you expect? What is `get_pages()` supposed to do? Can you show the code for `get_pages()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), `child_of` expects an integer, not an array. So in your case, you likely need multiple queries

```
$pages = [];

foreach ([403, 414, 417] as $id) {
    $pages = array_merge($pages, get_pages(['child_of' => $id]));
}
```

For php < 5.4, try this

```
$pages = array();

foreach (array(403, 414, 417) as $id) {
    $pages = array_merge($pages, get_pages(array('child_of' => $id)));
}
```

To sort your results after the queries...

```
usort($pages, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->post_date === $b->post_date) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a->post_date > $b->post_date ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code line with this stuff, but it shows to me like there is a syntax error O_O I'll update my question to a full code I have and if it is possible to use your code in my case..THANKS

Comment: i just replaced my child_of line with your code line, and it is shaowing syntax error. Maybe I do something wrong. I'm not coder so..

Comment: Likely you are using php < 5.4. Check your output of `php -v` and if it's less than 5.4 then replace all `[...]` with `array(...)`

Comment: I'm using godaddy linux deluxe hosting in phpMyadmin I found this  -  Version information: 4.0.10.7, latest stable version: 4.4.14.1   . So I need to try with array(...) ?

Comment: I think that's the phpmyadmin version, not the php version. Regardless, try using `array(...)` instead of `[...]`

Comment: Yes<333 that is perfectly working !! THANKS YOU SO MUCH!!! ^^ one more question how to sort it by post date desc? like in a previous version^^ THANKS!!!!!

Comment: you need to manually sort it since you are performing multiple queries. I will update my answer.

Comment: THANK YOU ONE MORE TIME! HAVE A GREAT DAY! ^^